# Restore a _remote_ file after solving a merge conflict using git

Tags: git, git-merge, git-stash

I've done several changes on my local files in a `parallel branch`. I used `git stash` to save my changes and to get other changes into `master` without having to push online. So I had to solve some merge conflicts about files redudants files. Step by step, this is my code on `git bash`:

```
git stash
git pull origin master
git stash pop
git mergetool
```

I solved conflict about one file `myFile.py` using `meld` as mergetool. My problem is that I forgot a huge part of code in the `remote` file (`myFile_remote_7572.py`) during the merge step. Right now, I'm not able to find the file anywhere on my laptop. I want to restore it in order to find my last code without restarting merge step. Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

While `git mergetool` likes to call some files *local* and others *remote*, it's really using a very bad set of names here.  Everything in Git is local!

Importantly, the file you want is in a commit that is going to be hard to find, as it was also entirely local, despite `git mergetool` calling it "remote".  I'm afraid this answer is going to be fairly long, too.  Here's the TL;DR:

- `git stash pop` is just `git stash apply && git stash drop`.  If the apply step fails with a merge conflict, this omits the `drop` step, which is good.
- The file you want was / is stored in a stash commit.
- If you still have the stash commit, you can get the entire file from there.  Since there was a merge conflict, `git stash pop` will not have dropped the stash on its own, so you may be in luck there.
- You may also be able to get the conflict back into the *index* (aka *staging area*), as long as you have not committed the result.
- If not, you may be able to *dig out* the stash commit, even if you have explicitly `git stash drop`ed it.

If the file is in an index staging slot, you can use `git show` to retrieve it:

```
git show :3:path/to/file.ext > /tmp/file.ext.recovered
```

This extracts the slot-3 version of `path/to/file.ext` to standard output, which here I redirect to a temporary file.

Or, if you find the `w` commit from the stash, you can use `git show <hash>:<path>` to view the saved file.  For instance, if `refs/stash` itself still refers to the `w` commit, you can easily run:

```
git stash show stash:path/to/file.ext > /tmp/file.ext.recovered
```

to get it back.

Read on to see what the `w` commit is and how to find it, if necessary, if you cannot get the file you want straight from the index.

#### Long

First, let me note that `git stash` just makes and uses commits.  When you run:

```
git stash        # aka "git stash save" or "git stash push"
...
git stash pop
```

you are creating a commit—well, two commits, really—at the save / push step, and then using that commit (one of the two) to perform a merge operation at the `pop` step.

Because the merge had conflicts, you need to know how merge really works.  Using `git mergetool` lets you defer learning some of the details for a while, but it's time to dig into them.

Now, each commit in Git records a complete snapshot of the entire source tree.  That's true of all regular commits, and also of the special commits that `git stash` makes.  In fact, the main thing that is special about the stash commits is that they are on *no* branch.

#### How branches grow, and what it means to be on a branch

In normal operation in Git, you are "on" some branch such as `master` or `develop`.  But what precisely does this mean?  Well, let's sit down for a moment and imagine we are starting a new, completely empty repository, with no commits at all.  We are on the branch `master`, but there are no commits.  So we create some files, run `git add` on them, and run `git commit`, which creates the very first commit.  It gets some big, ugly, seemingly-random hash ID, but for short let's just call it commit `A`.  Now we can draw out the existing situation:

```
A   <-- master
```

Commit `A` holds the full snapshot of all of our files.  Meanwhile the name `master` holds the hash ID of commit `A`, so we say that the name *points to* the commit.

To make a *new* commit, we make some changes to some file(s), run `git add`, and run `git commit` again.  Git now makes a new commit, with a new, unique, big ugly apparently-random ID.  This new commit `B` holds a full snapshot of all files—including files you *did not* change.  It also holds the big ugly hash ID of commit `A`.  So commit `B` now points to commit `A`.

Crucially, just after creating commit `B`, Git *changes* our name `master` to hold the ID of commit `B`.  So now `master` points to `B`, and `B` points to `A`:

```
A <-B   <-- master
```

This notion, that a branch name points to the *last* commit on a branch, gives us the name for that commit.  Git calls this the *tip* of the branch.  The branch *name* always simply identifies the last commit on the branch.

Once a commit is made, it can never be changed in any way.  (At most, you can decide you don't like `B`, and stop using it and start using a *new* commit that you prefer, that points back to, say, commit `A`.  If you make the name `master` point to the replacement for `B`, Git *seems* to have changed `B`, but in fact, there's just a different tip commit, with a new and different hash ID.)  So these internal arrows always go backwards and never change, so we can get away with just drawing lines.  That's more convenient for the case where we actually start branching our commits:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- master
          \
           G--H   <-- develop
```

Now that we have *two* branch names, with *two* branch tips, we need a way to know *which branch we're using*.  This is where the special name `HEAD` comes in: Git attaches the word `HEAD` to one of our various branches:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- master
          \
           G--H   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

This is what it means for *us* to be "on branch develop": if we make a new commit now, new commit `I` will point back to existing commit `H`, and Git will change `develop`—not `master`—to point to new commit `I`.

This also helps us figure out which commits are on which branch(es): commit `H` is on `develop` because it's the tip of `develop`, and commit `F` is on `master` because it's the tip of master.  But commit `G` is also on `develop` because, by starting at `H` and working backwards, we can *reach* commit `G`.  Likewise, commit `E` is on `master` because we can start at `F` and work backwards to get to `E`.

Interestingly, commits `D` and earlier are on *both* branches!  We can start at either tip and work backwards and get there.  Hence:

- Some commits are on more than one branch.  You find out by using the *names* to get to the *tip* commits, and then working backwards.
- The name `HEAD` identifies which branch *we're* on, by being attached to one of the branch names.

For (much) more about this, I suggest reading and working through the web site, [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

Note that like everything else about a commit, the snapshot contained inside each commit is completely read-only.  Nothing and no one can change *any* of these snapshot files.  Moreover, files inside snapshots are in a special, compressed, Git-only format.  This means you need an area in which *you* can work on / with your files, and that area is called the *work-tree* (or some minor spelling variant).

The files that you see, when you check out a commit, are in your work-tree.  Here, they have their ordinary uncompressed form, and you can read them, and write on them to change them.  These work-tree files are *not* stored in Git: they are only in your work-tree.  That's why you must be careful with, e.g., `git reset --hard`, which will *overwrite* your work-tree files.

#### The index, also called the staging area and the cache

It's easy to see the point of commits—they hold every saved version of every file forever, so that you can always go back and see what you saved—and it's equally easy to see the need for the work-tree, since the commits are read-only.  But Git has this strange thing halfway between commit and work-tree, which Git calls, variously, the *index*, the *staging area*, or sometimes the *cache* (depending on which bit of Git is doing the calling).

The best short description of the index is that it's *where you build the next commit you will make.*  It contains a copy of every file, starting with the copies extracted from the *current commit*.  That is, you `git checkout` some branch name, and Git extracts the commit to which that branch-name points.  But it really puts the commit into the *index* first.  The files in the index are still in the special, Git-only, compressed form.  Then Git expands those files into the work-tree into their usable form.  The key difference between the index copy and the committed copy is that you *can* overwrite the index copy.

This is what `git add` does: it just copies the work-tree version of a file into the index.  If the file was there before, that throws away the old version and stores the new one, compressed and ready to go into a new commit.  Until you run `git commit`, though, you can *keep on replacing* the file.  It's only when you run `git commit` that Git freezes the index versions into a commit.  (This is also *how* Git is so fast, compared to other systems that do not use this "index" idea.)

You might think you could get away without knowing about the index.  It's *almost* possible!  If you use `git commit -a` a lot, you can often pretend there's no index.  But in fact, the index takes on an expanded role during merges, so you *do* have to know about it.

#### Merges

At this point it's pretty easy to see how a regular `git merge` works.  Let's say you have the same graph as above, except that you run `git checkout master` to switch to the `master` branch:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- master (HEAD)
          \
           G--H   <-- develop
```

Now you'd like to incorporate work done on `develop` into `master`, so you run `git merge develop`.  What Git does at this point is *not* to just copy commit `H`.  If it did that, you would lose any changes you made in commits `E` and `F`.  Instead, Git reads back through the graph—starting at `H` and working backwards, and simultaneously, starting at `F` and working backwards—to find the *best common commit*.  Here, it's quite obvious which one is both shared (on both branches) and *best*, and that's commit `D`.

So at this point, Git runs, in effect, two separate `git diff` commands, to compare the snapshot in `D` against the two snapshots in `F`—what you've done, or changed since `D`, on branch `master`—and in `H`, what they have done on branch `develop`:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-D> <hash-of-F>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-D> <hash-of-H>   # what they changed
```

Git can now *combine* these changes, and apply the combined changes to the snapshot taken from commit `D`.  This combining of changes, from some common starting point, is the *action* part of `git merge`.  I like to say that this is the *to merge* verb: Git does the verb, the *to merge*, by comparing the common starting commit to the two ending commits, and combining the changes.

If all goes well—if there are no conflicts and Git thinks it has combined these two sets of changes correctly—Git will go ahead and make a new commit, using the combined changes.  The new commit adds on to the current branch, but unlike a regular commit, it points back to *both* of its two input commits.  The third input—the merge base—is implied: it's always going to be commit `D` since any future lookup starting from `F` and `H` will also find `D`.  This new commit is a *merge commit*, which uses the word *merge* as an adjective.  Git sometimes abbreviates this to just *a merge*, using the word *merge* as a noun:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--I   <-- master (HEAD)
          \      /
           G----H   <-- develop
```

Now merge commit `I` points back to both `F` and `H`, while the name `master` points to merge commit `I`, and the merge is complete.

#### Resolving conflicts, index staging slots, and how `git mergetool` works

**If the merge goes wrong**, though, Git stops in the middle of the merge!  In this case, Git leaves, for each conflicted file, *all three* copies of the file in the index.  The way this works is that Git has four *staging slots* per file name.  So if `README.txt` has a merge conflict, Git puts the *base* version of `README.txt`—from commit `D`—into staging slot 1, the `--ours` version of `README.txt` from commit `F` into staging slot 2, and the `--theirs` version of `README.txt` from commit `H` into staging slot 3.  Staging slot zero is reserved for files that *didn't* have a merge conflict, so Git removes anything from slot zero.

Git also puts its best effort at combining the three versions of `README.txt` into the work-tree.  You can edit this file in your own favorite editor (e.g., `vim README.txt`) and fix things up, if you like.  If you do that, you can then run `git add README.txt` as usual.  This tells Git to copy the work-tree version of `README.txt` into the index as usual; but this time, Git *removes* the three higher-stage entries, leaving you with just the stage-zero `README.txt`.  This is how Git knows that you have resolved the conflict.

Until you resolve the conflict, the higher stages remain in the index.  This is how Git knows that you *haven't* resolved the conflict.  So the index controls which files Git considers successfully merged.

If you like `git mergetool`, you can use it.  (I don't, and don't.)  What it does is look through the index<sup>1</sup> for these unmerged files.  Upon finding them, it extracts *all three* of the index entries into three temporary files, which it calls:

- base: for the merge base version from index slot 1
- local: for the `--ours` version from index slot 2
- remote: for the `--theirs` version from index slot 3

In an ordinary conflicted `git merge` style merge, these three copies are *also* available in the three commits, two of which have easy names: `HEAD` refers to the current branch, and `MERGE_HEAD` (which `git merge` writes out during the conflict) refers to the other commit—the one that `git mergetool` is calling *remote* even though it's a local commit.

So if this were an ordinary `git merge`, that would be where you could go to find your files.  But this is not `git merge`, this is `git stash pop`, and now we're finally ready to look at where these are and go.

---

<sup>1</sup>As I just found out yesterday or so, `git mergetool` interacts with `git rerere` to *ignore* unmerged files that `git rerere` has resolved, even though those retain their higher-stage entries.  If you don't use `git rerere`, this is not something to worry about.

---

#### Stashes

When `git stash save` or `git stash push` makes its commits—it normally makes two, one for the index  and one for the work-tree—they work a lot like any ordinary commit.  The main thing that is special about them, as we already noted, is that they are on *no* branches.  But they do, just like any ordinary commit, *point back* to other commits.  In fact, the *index* commit is an ordinary commit, and if the branch to which `HEAD` is attached were to advance as usual, `HEAD` would point to this index commit that I will call `i`:

```
...--J--K   <-- branch (HEAD)
         \
          i
```

The commit that `git stash save` or `git stash push` makes to hold the *work-tree*, which I call `w`, has the *form* of a merge commit because it has not one but two parents: it points back to commit `K` as its first parent, but to commit `i` as its second.  So we can draw this as:

```
...--J--K   <-- branch (HEAD)
        |\
        i-w   <-- refs/stash
```

Git uses the special (not-a-branch) name `refs/stash` to remember commit `w`.  Commit `w` remembers both commits `i` and (in this case) `K`.  So the stash knows *which commit it was on*.  It does not know, or care, which *branch* it was on—branch names don't really matter much in Git, after all—but it remembers which *commit* it was on, because commits matter.  (In a sense, commits are *all* that matter, in Git!)

It's when you run `git stash apply` or `git stash pop` that Git decides whether to *use* commit `i`.  Without `--index`, Git simply throws away commit `i` entirely, even though it carefully made it when you saved the stash.  It does this partly so that you can make the keep-or-discard-index decision later; but perhaps more because it's very easy, and in practice pretty much *necessary*, to make the `i` commit first while building the stash.  So we can kind of ignore the `i` commit here, since we're not going to use it.

Now that we have *made* the stash, now we might bring in some new commits.  Let's say that after commit `K`, we bring in more commits with a "fast forward" from `git pull`:

```
...--J--K--...--L   <-- branch (HEAD)
        |\
        i-w   <-- refs/stash
```

It's now time to `git stash apply` the `w` commit.

The way Git handles this is to run the *to merge* part of `git merge`!

One of the two main inputs to pretty much *any* merge is always the `HEAD` commit, which is now commit `L`.  The other main input is commit `w`.  Git uses `w`'s parent, commit `K`, as the merge base.<sup>2</sup>  So Git runs, in effect, two `git diff` commands as usual:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-K> <hash-of-L>   # what "we" did
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-K> <hash-of-w>   # what "they" did
```

Git now attempts to combine the two sets of changes and apply them to the snapshot from commit `K`.  If all goes well—of course it didn't, but if it had—Git would consider the "apply" complete, and discard (`pop`) the stash.  Git *does not* make a commit at this point, no matter what; that's always up to you.  The combining would and does happen in the index, though, using the work-tree to store Git's best effort in the case of conflicts.

If the combining *doesn't* go well, Git does it in the index, just like for `git merge`, and writes its best effort to the work-tree, just like for `git merge`.  It then stops—avoids `git stash drop`—and leaves you to clean up the mess.  If you choose to use `git mergetool`, that extracts the three versions from the three index staging slots as before.

If you still have the stash, the files are still there in the stash—in the `w` commit to which `refs/stash` points.  Hence `git show stash:<path>` will access it directly.

If `git mergetool` has not marked the file *resolved* (by moving a work-tree copy into stage-zero and wiping out the stage-1-through-3 entries), there is a copy in the index right now, and `git show :3:<path>` will get the `--theirs` copy out.  You can also use `git checkout --theirs <path>` to place that in the work-tree in its usual path (overwriting anything already there, so be careful).

You can even use `git checkout -m <path>` to *re-create* the merge conflict.  This is generally possible up until you commit the merged result.

---

<sup>2</sup>This is the natural and correct merge base, although `git stash apply` forces it anyway.

---

#### If you have dropped or cleared the stash

If you finished the to-merge verb action and ran `git stash drop` or `git stash clear`, you may be somewhat out of luck.  The only reference to commit `w` is now *gone*.  Git can *garbage collect* (`git gc`) the stash commit, typically once it's 14 days old, at this point.  However, you may be able to find it using `git fsck --lost-found`: see the recipe at the end of [the `git stash` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html).

Comment: Hi @Torek, thank you a lot for your help. To be honest, I've only read your TL;DR version above (thanks anyway for the long one, I'll have a look after). As I mentioned in my post the merge conflict was solved via `Meld`. So `git stash drop` have been runned on background as you mentionned. I'm not sure to find the ` index staging slot` you're talking about and I didn't do any commit yet. When I rerun `git mergetool` the terminal says `No files need merging`. It will be helpful if you can give me step by step instruction in this specific case as I'm real beginner on `git`. Thanks !

Comment: I've also a file in my directory. The name of this file is `myFile.py.ORIG`, I've seen some code into it. What does mean this file ?

Comment: I'm not sure precisely what mergetool does with meld, nor what meld itself does. The `.ORIG` file is a backup that `git mergetool` makes, to hold a copy of the work-tree file before the merge tool itself runs. You can view the entire index (including all staging slots) with `git ls-files --stage` but it's not user-oriented: it's meant more for working *on* Git than working *with* Git. As for whether the stash is still there, use `git stash list` to see all stashes...

Answer (score 0):

> It is not possible to restore the code without restarting merge step (in this scenario)

However, If you re-start the merge step, you will get to the desired state with the following steps:

**If `myFile_remote_7572.py` was in the stashed changes**

1. To return to master: `git checkout master`
2. To pull latest changes: `git fetch upstream; git merge upstream/master`
3. To correct my new branch: `git checkout new-branch; git rebase master`
4. To apply the correct stashed changes: `git stash apply`

*Git is smart enough not to drop a stash if it doesn't apply cleanly.*

---

**If `myFile_remote_7572.py` was on the remote**

1. Pull the latest changes: `git fetch`
2. Checkout file from the remote: `git checkout origin/master -- path/to/file/myFile_remote_7572.py`

*The `fetch` will download all the recent changes, but it will not put it in your current checked out code (working area).*

*The `checkout` will update the working tree with the particular file from the downloaded changes (`origin/master`).*

Comment: That is, unfortunately, going to be the wrong file. The file labeled "remote" during the `git mergetool` run is the one that was in the stash.